# diff is not working in execSync producing error when file doesnot match

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

diff command gives error when my files does not match `const exec_options = { cwd : "/home" ,  encoding  : 'utf8', }`

```
    let {stdout,stderr,err} =    execSync(`diff  output.txt answer.txt` , exec_options);
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
console.log(stdout);
```

The above command gives desired result with exec and in terminal but does not work using exec sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `execSync` returns string or buffer

Your code should be..

```
const stdout = execSync(`diff output.txt answer.txt` , exec_options);
console.log(stdout.toString());
```

if you want to configure `stderr` and `stdout`, uses `spawnSync`

### Why `execSync` is fail ?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/698784/exit-code-of-diff

because, `diff` returns non-zero when something is different.

and `execSync` determines normal termination only when the value is 0.

so if something is different, `diff` returns 1, and `execSync` guess command failed.

actually we get that message.

```
  try {
    let stdout = execSync(`diff a b`, exec_options)
    console.log(stdout.toString())
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log(e.message)
    console.log(e.stdout.toString())
  }
```

```bash
Command failed: diff a b
2c2
< a
---
> b
```

### some test

```
  try {
    const command = 'diff a c'
    console.log(`command : ${command}`)
    let stdout = execSync(command, exec_options)
    console.log(stdout.toString())
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log('prev')
    if (e.status === 1) {
      console.log('diff result:')
      console.log(e.stdout.toString())
      console.log(e.stderr.toString())
    } else {
      console.log('error message : ')
      console.log(e.stdout.toString())
      console.log(e.stderr.toString())
    }
  }
```

will print

```
command : diff a a // in same case
                   // nothing returns
~~~~~~~~
command : diff a b // in diff case
prev
diff result:
2c2                // e.stdout exist
< a
---
> b
                   // e.stderr doesn't exist
~~~~~~~~
command : diff a c // in fail case
diff: c: No such file or directory // print at execSync.
prev
error message : 
                   // e.stdout doesn't exist
diff: c: No such file or directory // e.stderr exist
```

Comment: ok so diff sends exits with 1 when the file doesnot matches , It worked thanks for detailed explanation